# Conceptual issue with coding Otsu's method - skimage.filters.thresholding.threshold_otsu

Tags: python, scikit-image, image-thresholding

Otsu's method performs binary image thresholding and consists of maximising the variance between the two subclasses (foreground/background) created by splitting the image at a given threshold.  Mathematically, this is expressed as:

`variance12 = weight1 * (mean1 - meanT)**2 + weight2 * (mean2 - meanT)**2`

(meanT is the overal mean of the image histogram).  However, I'm having trouble with understanding how this is implemented in the `threshold_otsu` function in `scikit-image` which writes this as:

`variance12 = weight1 * weight2 * (mean1 - mean2)**2`.

Though the definitions of the weights and means are slightly different in this function, I can't see how these two formulations are the same - even though they give the same answers.  Would someone care to clarify?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove the two formulations are the same by using the definitions of the weights and meanT.

```
meanT = weight1*mean1 + weight2*mean2  (1)
weight1 + weight2 = 1                  (2)
```

If you insert (1) into your first formula, you end up with something like this

```
[(mean1-mean2)**2]*[weight1*weight2**2] + [(mean1-mean2)**2]*[weight2*weight1**2]
```

If you factor that and use (2), you'll get your result.

The complete proof is below, and the definitions can be checked in [Otsu's original paper here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4310076).

Hope this helps.
[image: Proof of Otsu threshold formula]

Comment: Thanks @NeverNervous.  How silly of me not to have carried through my algebra!

Comment: No problems! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped :)